# VBA Macro to convert OLE to text results in "Word has encountered a prob." error

Tags: vba, popup, ms-word

I am using the following VBA script to parse through a word document and open every OLE table object, copy the table, and paste back into word so that the data in the tables can be searchable. However, after the script runs for a while, Word gives me an error message stating "Word has encountered a problem. You will not be able to undo this action once it is completed. Do you want to continue?" Clicking yes leads the document to stop responding and crash with no changes been made. Choosing No just keeps repopping up the same message and I'm assuming this leads to the changes not being saved. Is something wrong with the script ? I thought it was somehow filling up the memory by opening all those OLE objects, but I think activating the word document shifts focus from the OLE object and hence closes the embedded table to continue parsing through the original document. I think it's probably related to each iteration of the loop although the message doesn't show up for every OLE table. I am stuck as to how to investigate further into what is causing this issue.

```
    wrdActDoc.InlineShapes(lShapeCnt).OLEFormat.Activate
    Selection.Document.Select
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Cut
    wrdActDoc.Activate
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
```

Comment: how many Ole object do you have in your document? Try to run macro only for few of them to check if macro is able to complete. There could be many reason but one is memory limited resources. you could try to debug your subroutine. Try to put `Stop` at the end of inner loop- it would required manual triggering for each object but you would be able to find which object is causing a problem (which could be the other reason of errors).

Comment: Hundreds of OLEs in a couple of thousand page document. Stop isn't really an option since the message only starts to appear a few hundred pages down the road, unless I manually extract parts of the document and try which would be very time consuming. I am not sure as to what the error messsage is suggesting or what it is as a result of.. It seems to be random too, getting me a bit puzzled.

Comment: if you want to solve the problem it seems that you need to expect some manual work and tests. at the first stage you could try to stop every 10th Ole object, next go to details knowing the section when error occurs. To stop every 10th use this function `Debug.Assert i / 10 <> Int(i / 10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Googled for "Word undo" and found the following:

"be sure to save once in a while since the undo stack will be cleared"

So, for example, safe the document [to a temp name] after processing every 10 objects.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That actually greatly reduced the number of times the message comes up. It seems the more objects I iterate through before saving, the more times the message comes up. However, for some reason, word stops responding, stops iterating through the objects and is not updating the file, and eventually crashes. I am not sure as to what is causing this.

Comment: Then please click on the vote to accept the partial answer :-)